# How can I obtain a reference to a control created inside a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have one control named thumbviewer inside repeater. I want to set its imageurl in
code. Currently it's done in aspx itself as

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span style="padding:2px 10px 2px 10px">

                            <bri:ThumbViewer Id="Th1"  runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "images/{0}") %>' Height="100px" Width="100px"/>
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

How can i set ImageUrl in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected void rpter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ThumbViewControl control = e.Item.FindControl("Th1") as ThumbViewControl;
        if (control != null)
        {
           control.ImageUrl = "";
        }
    }
}
```

and on the aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpter_ItemDataBound" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span style="padding:2px 10px 2px 10px">

                            <bri:ThumbViewer Id="Th1"  runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px"/>
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Is how I would personally do it.

If you wish to get the data for it, at that point, I believe e.Item.DataItem (or something similar) get its.

Cheers,

T

Comment: snap! Fair play for adding the checks for null.  Thats useful practice to get into, even if you're 100% the control will be there!

Comment: it will effectively check for if the control is there, and if a control is there by that id, that is of type "ThumbViewControl" or whatever, so it's kind of two checks in one.

I do love "as" :)

Answer (score 2):

Your repeater has a onitemdatabound event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound"></asp:Repeater>
```

In your code behind you can have an Event handler called

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // ensure that we only look in the item template for our control
    if(  e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
         ThumbViewer tv = (ThumbViewer)e.Item.FindControl("Th1");
         tv.ImageUrl = "images/"+((<The object type you are binding>)e.Item.DataItem).Name;
    }
}
```

This is the most orthodox way to access data being bound to a repeater. IMHO

HTH

Comment: According to code i updated what i have to write in place of The
object type you are binding.Pls help

Comment: Just to be clear, the object that is being bound to the repeater has a Name property.  When you are casting the e. Item.DataItem object to the desired type,
it should look something like this:

MyType myCoolType = (MyType)e.Item.DataItem;

that's the basic way.

but to shorten this code you can write

tv.ImageUrl = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).Name;

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the repeater and then look through the controls:

I do a similar thing here and load a control into a placeholder inside of a repeater..

```
        if (ResultRepeater != null && ResultRepeater.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control oControl in ResultRepeater.Controls)
            {
                if (oControl != null && oControl is RepeaterItem)
                {
                    PlaceHolder oSuggestMorePlaceholder = (PlaceHolder) oControl.FindControl("SuggestMorePlaceholder");

                    if (oSuggestMorePlaceholder != null)
                    {
                        SuggestMoreTabbedControl oTabbedControl = (SuggestMoreTabbedControl) Page.LoadControl("controls/SuggestMoreControl.ascx");
                        if (oTabbedControl != null)
                        {
                            oSuggestMorePlaceholder.Controls.Add(oTabbedControl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dude, you need to check out the FindControl() method

Comment: Isn't FindControl() recursive? Kind of expensive if it is. Better off using it in one of the onitemdatabound event solutions suggested below.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000307.html

No, it's not recursive unfortunately...

Comment: I think you are mistaken, @Gordon... FindControl() *is* recursive. Look at the comments to Jeff's post (CodingHorror) if you don't believe me.